# A local ring with a unique minimal ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1 such that it is local with a unique non-idempotent minimal ideal, that is, there are two ideals $I$ and $m$ of $R$ such that for each ideal $K$ of $R$ with $0\not=K\not=R$ we have $I\subseteq K\subseteq m$ and $I^2=0$. I am looking for a characterization for such a ring.

Comment: Just a comment: among commutative Artinian local rings, the ones with unique minimal ideals are the quasi-Frobenius rings.

Comment: In case it helps to complement Sandor's answer, I know of [three examples](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=23&H=98l&H=101l&L=64l&L=10) of non Noetherian rings satisfying your conditions.  Two are uniserial, one is not.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that if $R$ is Noetherian, then this implies that it is an Artinian Gorenstein ring and conversely the condition holds for those. Here is why:

By your condition $I\subseteq \mathfrak m^n$ for every $n$ for which $\mathfrak m^n\neq 0$, but by the Krull intersection theorem the intersection of all of those is zero which implies that there must be an $n$ for which $\mathfrak m^n= 0$. This implies that $R$ is Artinian.

Your condition also implies that then $I$ is the socle of $R$ and it has to have dimension $1$ as a vector space over the residue field of $R$. That implies that $R$ is Gorenstein.

Conversely, the socle of an Artinian Gorenstein ring has dimension $1$ as a vector space over the residue field of $R$ and it is an essential submodule of $R$ which implies both of your conditions.

Comment: Nice application!